# which constructor will be called when operator = is used in class initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I thought operator"=" only call copy construtor or assign construtor, but some different remind me this is wrong. like following code

```
class B {
  public:
    explicit B(int* pi)
        : i_(pi), deleter(nullptr) {
        std::cout << "type convert"<<std::endl;
    }
    B(int* pi, void (*del)())
        : i_(pi), deleter(del) {
        std::cout << "double cons"<<std::endl;
    }
    B(const B& rhs) {
        std::cout << "copy"<<std::endl;
    }
    B& operator=(const B& rhs) {
        std::cout << "="<<std::endl;
        i_ = rhs.i_;
        deleter = rhs.deleter;
        return *this;
    }
    ~B() {
        std::cout << "dest"<<std::endl;
    }

  private:
    int* i_;
    void (*deleter)();
};

void test() {
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    B pb(new int(4));
    B pc = {new int(3), test};
    B pd = {new int(3)};

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the output is

```
type convert
double cons
// pd is wrong
```

I thought the output is

```
type convert
double cons ->copy 
type convert
```

of course, pb called type convert constructor. but pc called constructor with two arguments. and pd is wrong called.
so my questions:how operator= chose appropriate constructor?

Comment: The shown class does not have a "default constructor", so your claim that one was called is incorrect.

Comment: Provide the current output and your expected output. The program **doesn't even compile**. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/pLn-cKW9T) Also you're **missing a return statement** inside `operator=`.

Comment: I changed the word, thank you for you correction.

Comment: `operator=` is not called in your code